# Javascript - resume page refresh after window.stop

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

I have this refresher set in the page - it does a forced reload every 5 minutes.

```js
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300"/>
```

Now I want to stop refreshing at certain action (like opening a modal form).

In the modal opening event I can add

```js
window.stop()
```

to prevent the refresh. But how can I resume the refresh rate after closing the modal? Without a need to refresh the page.

In other words  I want only to suspenend refreshing the page for the period of displaying modeal.

Comment: don't use a meta refresh. use a javascript timer.